# Phone app keeps crashing

Tags: applications, crashes, system-apps

Launch the Phone app, then `3 dots > Settings` and every time the app crashes with the message "Phone has stopped". I was trying to block a number. How do I go about diagnosing why this is happening?

If relevant, running Android 7.1.1 on a Motorola G4 Play.

Comment: For uncovering the reason you may need to connect your phone to a PC via USB, enable Developer options on device, install Android SDK/sdb on the PC and execute `adb logcat` to see the Android real-time log. If then the error occurs you should see more details in logcat.

Comment: OK, thanks...something to try over the weekend! Full testing is never feasible, I realise, but I do wish developers of (especially core system) apps would test things in a variety of scenarios and hardware platforms before pushing out bugware which may or may not be fixed with the next update.